# How to Dismiss view from viewModel in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have one view with MVVM architecture. in view on button click i am calling webService from viewModel class on success i want to dismiss view.

my viewmodel is `ObservableObject`

i am moving to other screen using navigation and not using sheet

I have tried this

```
@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>
`self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()`
```

in view but it will call before API call.

is there any way to dismiss view once i receive API data in viewModel?

Thank you for help

Comment: do you have a model type ObservableObject?

Comment: @SimonePistecchia yes

Comment: did you try to use onReceive? please add minimal reproducible code

Answer (score 3):

I didn't compile my code but I think this approach should work. I used something like this in my pet-projects

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    var didSendRequest: AnyPublisher<Void, Never> {
        subject.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    
    private let subject = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var viewModel: ViewModel
    
    @Environment(\.presentationMode)
    var presentationMode
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello")
        }
        .onReceive(viewModel.didSendRequest) { _ in
            presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }
    }
}
```

In your view model when you receive a response you should execute the next code:

```
subject.send()
```

Answer (score 1):

In your ObservableObject, set an @Published var indicating that the API load is complete.

```
class APIController: ObservableObject {
    @Published var apiLoaded = false;
    
    func doTheApiLoad() {
        ...
        //when you want to dismiss
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.apiLoaded = true;
        }
    }
```

}

In your content view, watch that published value

```
@ObservedObject var apiController: APIController()
```

When it changes, dismiss the view

```
if (apiController.apiLoaded == true) {
    presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
}
```